# Rails scoping embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, mongoid

I'm trying to get a list of upcoming books due by doing this:

```
scope :upcoming, lambda { where('books.date_due' => {'$lt' => Date.yesterday + 7.days, '$gt' => Date.today - 14.days})
```

But I need to limit it to the first embedded document...this queries all embedded documents per book...

Do I add an additional query by the `created_at` field to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `embeds_many` embedded document is really just an array of hashes with some Mongoid wrapping. That means that you can use the usual array notations for looking at specific elements in the array; in particular, you can say:

```
where('books.0.date_due' => { ... })
#            ^ element zero is the first entry
```

Comment: What if I need the last document?? :|